# How to force bibtex to use "\:" between second and last names in gost705?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Say we have an author "Armstrong, Andrey Vasilievich" and we want bibtex to generate Armstrong`\:`A.`\:`V. what shall we change in [gost705](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/disser/src/gost705.dtx) style?

I tried to play with `FUNCTION {format.names}` yet I always get Armstrong`\:`A.`~`V. instead.=(

Comment: Do you mean `$\:$`, ie a math-mode thickspace?

Comment: Yes  thickspace was meant

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The following line in `FUNCTION {format.names}` does the trick:

```
  "{vv~}{ll}{{$\;$}f{.$\;$}.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

instead of  the original

```
   "{vv~}{ll}{~f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

Here the first `$\;$` refers to the space before all first names, the second `.$\;$` to the separation between the first names (including the period), and the last period to the token after the last first name.